# Python - index in string to matching word

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert an index in a string to the word the index is in.

For example, if this is my string:

```
This is a very stupid string
```

and the index I get is, let's say 10, so the output should be `very`. 
Also if the index is 11,12 or 13 - the output should be `very`.

One can assume that the words are separated by 1 space each time. 
Doing it with a for loop or something is not hard, the question is whether there is a more efficient way (as my text is HUGE and I have MANY indices to convert to words).

For the example, let the indices be 10, 13, 16 and thus the output should be:

```
10 very
13 very
16 stupid
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with loops? You just go directly to your position and move both left and right until current char is space. Complexity is O(n) if there is only one word in string with length of n

Comment: What happens for things like `index=4` where it's not inside a word?

Comment: Is the HUGE text all in memory already or does it have to be processed from a stream?

Comment: @JonClements - good point. assume it won't happen

Comment: @jingx assume it's in memory

Comment: Could you build a list of indices of where the letter is a space, then [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should perform quite well. Begin by obtaining the words in the string using `split`, and find the indedx where they begin using `enumerate` and a list comprehension:

```
words = s.split()
# ['This', 'is', 'a', 'very', 'stupid', 'string']
# Obtain the indices where all words begin
ix_start_word = [i+1 for i,s in enumerate(s) if s==' ']
# [5, 8, 10, 15, 22]
```

And now you could use `NumPy's` [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to obtain a word given an index:

```
words[np.searchsorted(ix_start_word, ix)]
```

Checking with the examples above:

```
words[np.searchsorted(ix_start_word, 11)]
#'very'

words[np.searchsorted(ix_start_word, 13)]
# 'very'

words[np.searchsorted(ix_start_word, 16)]
# 'stupid'
```

Comment: Good solution. Just need to add a `[0]` to `ix_start_word`

Comment: Is it faster to use a for loop on `words` to calculate ix_start_word than enumerating through `s`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly proud of how clean this is, but I think it does the trick:

```
from numpy import cumsum, array

sample = 'This is a very stupid string'

words = sample.split(' ')
lens = [len(_)+1 for _ in words]

ends = cumsum(lens)
starts = array([0] + list(ends[:-1]))

output = {}
for a, b, c in zip(starts, ends, words):
    for i in range(a, b):
        output[i] =  c
for a, b in output.items():
    print(a, b)
```

```
0 This
1 This
2 This
3 This
4 This
5 is
6 is
7 is
8 a
9 a
10 very
11 very
12 very
13 very
14 very
15 stupid
16 stupid
17 stupid
18 stupid
19 stupid
20 stupid
21 stupid
22 string
23 string
24 string
25 string
26 string
27 string
28 string
```

Comment: It could use some comprehension for the loop where output is populated and I don't remember how to append np arrays, so I did a quick and dirty solution turning them to lists and then to arrays

Comment: If the intent is to build a index->word dictionary lookup as you're doing then you can simplify this to just: `output = {i: m.group() for m in re.finditer('[^ ]+', s) for i in range(*m.span())}`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very effective, because it uses regular-expression, but is one way to solve the problem without using any loops.

```
import re

def stuff(pos):
    x = "This is a very stupid string"
    pattern = re.compile(r'\w+\b')
    pattern2 = re.compile(r'.*(\b\w+)')
    end = pattern.search(x, pos=pos).span()[1]
    print(pattern2.search(x, endpos=end).groups()[0])

stuff(2)
stuff(10)
stuff(11)
stuff(16)
```

Results:

```
This
very
very
stupid
```